# Launch an action when keyword is detected by Pocketsphinx

Tags: android, android-studio, speech-recognition, pocketsphinx

I am using pocketsphinx to detect the word camera and launch camera application. However, as soon as I say "camera", although it opens the camera, but the screen starts to flicker (brightness increases and decreases) and camera lags. Also, after pressing backbutton to close the camera, the camera app opens itself again. I fail to understand what's wrong here?

```
public class PocketSphinxActivity extends Activity implements
    RecognitionListener {


private static final String trigger = "camera";
//private static final String KWS_SEARCH="wakeup";

private SpeechRecognizer recognizer;
private HashMap<String, Integer> captions;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    super.onCreate(state);



    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Exception>() {
        @Override
        protected Exception doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Assets assets = new Assets(PocketSphinxActivity.this);
                File assetDir = assets.syncAssets();
                setupRecognizer(assetDir);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                return e;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Exception result) {
            if (result != null) {
                result.printStackTrace();
            } else {
                recognizer.startListening(trigger);
            }
        }
    }.execute();
}

@Override
public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
}

@Override
public void onPartialResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
    if (hypothesis == null)
        return;

    String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();
    if (text.equals(trigger)){
    Intent i=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if(i.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null){
        startActivity(i);
    }
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
    //no use
}

@Override
public void onEndOfSpeech() {
}

@Override
public void onError(Exception error) {
    error.printStackTrace();
}

@Override
public void onTimeout() {
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    recognizer.cancel();
    recognizer.shutdown();
}

private void setupRecognizer(File assetsDir) throws IOException{
    recognizer=defaultSetup()
            .setAcousticModel(new File(assetsDir, "en-us-ptm"))
            .setDictionary(new File(assetsDir, "cmudict-en-us.dict"))
            .setKeywordThreshold(1e-45f)
            .setBoolean("-allphone_ci", true)
            .getRecognizer();
    recognizer.addListener(this);
    recognizer.addKeyphraseSearch(trigger,"camera");
}
```

}

Comment: You need to stop recognition when keyword is detected otherwise it will launch camera again and again.

Comment: What line and where do I need to add the code to stop the recognition? Its also working for every word I speak.

Comment: It's still a bit sensitive. Since after speaking words other than camera, it does not opens but when I finally speak camera, it fails to do any action. Why so?

Comment: Sensitivity is controlled by a threshold in your code, you have to tune it. Values like 1e-20 or 1e-10 have more sense than 1e-45. "camera" keyphrase is a bit short, you probably want slightly longer keyphrase. As for restarting the search, once the camera is done you need to restart listening so it will react on keywords again.

Comment: You mean, after recognizer.stop(), I should write recognizer.startlistening("camera") ?

Comment: Not right after but in some moment you need to start listen again. Maybe after camera is closed. Maybe after a timeout.

Comment: Thanks Nikolay. I've increased the key phrase length and it works fine now. Two letter commands are optimum.